# WCF and generic class c#

Tags: c#, wcf, generics

I have a problem with creating wcf service, which return list of generic object. Sample code:

```
  [KnownType( typeof( Enum1 ) )]
  [KnownType( typeof( Enum2 ) )]
  [KnownType( typeof( Enum3 ) )]
  [DataContract( Name = "ChangeContainerOf{0}" )]
  public class BaseChangeContainer<T>
      where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
  {
    [DataMember( IsRequired = true )]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember( IsRequired = true )]
    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember( IsRequired = true )]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [DataMember( IsRequired = true )]
    public List<BaseChangeItem<T>> ChangesList { get; set; }


    public BaseChangeContainer()
    {

    }

    public BaseChangeContainer( IChange item, List<BaseChangeItem<T>> changesList)
    {
      Id = item.Id;
      UserId = item.IdReporter;
      ChangesList = changesList;
    }
  }


  [KnownType( typeof( Enum1 ) )]
  [KnownType( typeof( Enum2 ) )]
  [KnownType( typeof( Enum3 ) )]
  [DataContract( Name = "ChangeItemOf{0}" )]
  public class BaseChangeItem<T>
    where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
  {
    [DataMember( IsRequired = true )]
    public T ChangeType { get; set; }

    [DataMember( IsRequired = true )]
    public ChangeCategory Category { get; set; }

    [DataMember( IsRequired = true )]
    public string Description { get; set; }


public BaseChangeItem()
{

}

    public BaseChangeItem( T changeType, ChangeCategory category, string description )
    {
      ChangeType = changeType;
      Category = category;
      Description = description;
    }
  }
```

Here is definition of the service

```
public List<BaseChangeContainer<Enum1>> GetLog( int id )
```

Note that all enums are DataContract.

I getting error: Referenced type 'BaseChangeContainer' with data contract name 'ChangeContainerOfEnum1 in namespace (...) cannot be used since id does not match imported DataContract.

What am i doing wrong?

Thank You for helping me.

**edit:**
I found out that error is caused by `ChangesList` property - when i delete it, problems not occur.

Comment: This may not be the root cause of your problem, but did you mark all enum values as `EnumMember`?

Comment: Yes I did, unfortunately it's not the problem :(